# ocl constraint on collection size

Tags: constraints, ocl

[draw of my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuwEj.png)
In the link above, we can see the class `Student` and `Class`. I want to make an invariant constraint to make sure a `Student` can't register for more than 5 classes each `sessionYear`.

With this constraint, I can determine if `Student` as more than 5 classes

```
context Student
inv maxClassStudent: classTaken->collect(sessionYear)->size() < 6
```

But, what I want is to find the size for a collection formed only with the same `sessionYear`. In other words, I wish to make a collection for every different `sessionYear` to verify if, for that year, the `Student` had less than 6 classes.

I thought that I could maybe make use of `forAll(c1,c2|c1<>c2 implies c1.sessionYear <> c2.sessionYear)` or something similar to difference `Class` based on its `sessionYear`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard problems are often soluble by breaking them into smaller pieces...

let sessionYears = classTaken->collect(sessionYear)->asSet()
in sessionYears->forAll(sy | classTaken->select(sessionYear = sy)->size() < 6)

Comment: oh, so the select is the answer here. I had a hard time figuring out how to break my collection into smaller pieces, but with `select(sessionYear = sy)`, I get a collection for every different `sy`. Thanks a lot